# segmentation fault at closing brace

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

This is my first post.

I've tried to keep the instructions in mind, but I apologize in advance if I missed something.

The program is an assignment for class where we are to make a gradebook using three different linked lists (students, courses and transactions, for want of a better word).

The block I'm posting will search through the list (assuming there is one, looking for an existing object with the same information, that is what the `csearch` function does.

If it doesn't find one, then it creates a new object, and sets about putting it in the list, always at the tail.

All of this works, until it reaches the closing brace of the function, and then it segmentation faults.

I've spent the better part of the day trying to figure out why this is happening, and I was hoping you could help me out.

```
    void classes::addcourse(classes section)
   {
   int courseid;
   char  title[81];
   course *temp= NULL, *search=NULL;

   cout<<"Please enter the course id number."<<endl;
   cin>>courseid;getchar();

   cout<<"Please enter a course name."<<endl;
   cin>>title;

   search=section.csearch(courseid);               
   if (search != NULL)
      {                                                  
      cout<<"This course has already been entered."<<endl;  
      return;                                            
      }

   temp=new course(courseid);
   if (head==NULL)
      {
      sethead(temp);
      settail(temp);
      }
   tail->setnext(temp);
   settail(temp);
   section.setcnum(section.getcnum()+1);
   cout<<section.getcnum()<<endl;
   temp->setname(title);
   }
```

In case it is helpful, here are the class definitions for the objects and the container, which are stored separately in a .h file.

```
class course {
   private:
   int cid;
   int average;
   course *next;
   char name[81];

   public:
   course(int);
   void saveyourself(FILE *write);
   void loadyourself(FILE *read);

   //accessor functions
   int getcid() {return cid;}
   int getaverage() {return average;}
   course* getnext() {return next;}

   //mutator functions
   void setnext(course *val) {next=val;}
   void getname() {cout<<name;}
   void setcid (int newcid) {cid=newcid;}
   void setaverage (int newav) {average=newav;}
   void setname (char word[]) {strcpy(name, word);}
};

class classes {
   private:
   course *head;
   course *tail;
   int numcourse;

   public:
   classes();
   ~classes();
   course* csearch (int course);
   void addcourse(classes section);
   void classaverage(enrollment semester, classes section);
   void save();
   void load();

   //accessor functions
   int getcnum() {return numcourse;}
   course* gethead() {return head;}
   course* gettail() {return tail;}

   //mutator functions
   void setcnum(int num) {numcourse=num;}
   void sethead(course *val) {head=val;}
   void settail(course *val) {tail=val;}   

};
```

In case it comes up, I am using character arrays for strings because that is what I finally settled on when I got tired of switching back and forth.

Edit: Sorry about not adding constructors, I forgot about them, here they are:

```
course::course(int id=-1)
   {
   cid=id;
   average=0;
   strcpy(name, "name");
   next=NULL;
   }


classes::classes()
   {
   numcourse=0;
   head=NULL;
   tail=NULL;
   }
```

I've always been paranoid about uninitialized strings, so that's why it's already set to something. I usually initialize them to "\0", but that makes me worry about file I/o.

Comment: Have you tried using Valgrind?

Comment: Your problem almost certainly lies in your failure to follow [The Rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: I can suggest two possibilities. (1) The closing brace runs dtors for objects you have made in the block.  So a dtor might be causing the crash.  (2) Your array title[81] could have overflowed and trashed the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is doing what you want:

```
   cin>>title;
```

If you're going to use C-style character arrays, you probably want to use `cin.getline()` like so:

```
   cin.getline(title, 81);
```

That will ensure you do not overflow `title[]`, and it will put a NUL terminator at the end.  It will also eat the newline at the end and not put it in `title[]`.

More information here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/?kw=istream%3A%3Agetline

Comment: getline is something I've gone back and forth about using, with no noticeable difference in results. I haven't used any kind of debugging tool more complex than the one included in Visual c++ Express, and that gave a message of 0x0000000c <Bad Ptr> in reference to name, but I'm not sure what line that refers to.

Comment: Where do you initialize `head` and `tail`.  I don't see code in your constructor to do so, but then your constructor isn't visible in the code above.